# How to hide all rows with the word HELLO in a table. If WORLD is not equal to WORLD in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have such a minor problem, I try to find in Javascript all **TD** in the table that does not contain the words **WORLD** after clicking on the **"ONLY WORLD"** button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dataTableText = document.getElementById("data-table").innerText;
  let btnOW = document.getElementById("btn-only-world");

  if (dataTableText === 'Hello') {
    $('table tbody').find('td').style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-table">
  <table class="table table-bordered text-center table-dark" id="data-table">
    <tr>
      <td>Only World</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
    <button id="btn-only-world" class="btn btn-light" type="button">Only World</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ``dataTableText`` return multiple strings of **hello world**, thus your ``if (dataTableText === 'Hello')`` will never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the correct td to hide, here I have updated your code sippet.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="data-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered text-center table-dark" id="data-table">
            <tr>
                <td>Only World</td>
                <td>b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>World</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>World</td>
                <td>World</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>World</td>
                <td>World</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>World</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrap">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
            <button id="btn-only-world" class="btn btn-light" type="button">Only World</button>
            <button id="btn-all-world" class="btn btn-light" type="button">All</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {



        $("#btn-only-world").click(function () {
            $("td").each(function (column, td) {
                var cellText = $(this).html();
                if (cellText === "Hello")
                    $(td).css("display", "none")

            });
        });

        $("#btn-all-world").click(function () {
            $("td").each(function (column, td) {
                var cellText = $(this).html();
                $(td).removeAttr("style")

            });
        });


    });
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code works :) please don't know how to hide unless Hello World is equal, ie if Hello is Hello or World World

Comment: If I get your question coreectly. You can change the if condition `if (cellText === "Hello")` according to you need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code it looks like you're using jquery, rather than just plain javascript.

I've updated your snippet to:

- Run your function based on a button click, rather than as soon as the document is ready
- Find all td's with the word "Hello" using the JQuery `:contains()` selector
- Set a class with the css `visibility: hidden`, because using display: none would make the TD's disappear completely and mess up your table layout. If you wanted the cells gone completely, you should still do `display: none`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let tdsWithHello = $("table#data-table td:contains('Hello')");

  $("#btn-only-world").click(function() {
      tdsWithHello.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hide"); 
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-table">
  <table class="table table-bordered text-center table-dark" id="data-table">
    <tr>
      <td>Only World</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
    <button id="btn-only-world" class="btn btn-light" type="button">Only World</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `dataTableText` will never be `"Hello"`. It will be the text value of the complete table. Your `if`-condition is therefore never true.

So this line:

```
$('table tbody').find('td').style.display = "none";
```

is never executed. If it were, it would hide all `<td>`s in the table, regardless of their content.